# How to Clone an Azure Devops Repo in Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm facing some issues while trying to clone Azure Devops repo to VsCode. The error message says failed to connect to devops. I have tried opening the clone url from the browser and it works.
Is there a confirguration issue?

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: Try to run `git clone <url>` from command line in the box where vscode is running.

Comment: Could be a proxy issue, your browser already has it, your terminal may not. https://blog.victorsilva.com.uy/failed-to-connect-to-github/

Comment: @jellyboy tried using the command line and got the same error message

Comment: @thenewbee well that proves the point that it's not a vscode issue. You have some sort of block/firewall from where you are up to the git repo.